# owncloudcmd crashses (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: owncloud-client

Before upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04 the following command line worked. Now it crashes:

```
===> LANG=C owncloudcmd --silent --non-interactive -u myuser -n  py-pics/2017/ http://example.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/2017/
Set proxy configuration to use system configuration
Cannot load system exclude list or list supplied via --exclude
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

For some reason I could not get the last line to be in english language. It means: aborted (core dumped).

Version:

```
owncloudcmd version 2.2.4
```

What can I do to get it working again?

Answer (score 1):

After installing owncloud-client (the GUI) it worked:

```
sudo apt install owncloud-client
```

Comment: @Videonauth what should I add? What are you missing?

Comment: @Videonauth I added the obvious. But I guess you are right. This makes it easier for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

Works here with the Nextcloud client. Not sure what the issue is. Have you tried the latest version? 2.3 is released already.